# Adding Django models constraints?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the model Period as below:

```
class Period(models.Model):
      number = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
      start_time = models.TimeField()
      end_time = models.TimeField()
```

How can I add constraints to make `Period.start_time < Period.end_time` and Period models have the order like this?

> Period 1: 7:00-7:50; Period 2: 7:50-8:40; ...

The field number express the order of the period instance. My approach is adding methods to check if it is valid . However, I want to know that there is any database way to do this.

Comment: Preferably sou would do this in Javascrpt before anything gets saved to the database.

Comment: ... or you override the models save method but you have to catch the wrong data entry in the view then.

Comment: @ger.s.brett Doing this in JS is a bad idea. Someone can simply disable JS on their browser and then submit the wrong data. However, doing this inside `save` method (or anywhere else in the server side code) is the correct and safer way.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in several methods

**Method -1:** Override the **`save()`** method of `Period` model as

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class Period(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.end_time < self.start_time:
            raise ValidationError("some message")
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Method -2:** Override the **`clean()`** method of model

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class Period(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()  # calling default cleaning
        if self.end_time < self.start_time:
            raise ValidationError("some message")
```

**Method - 3:** Override the **`full_clean()`** method

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class Period(models.Model):
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()

    def full_clean(self, exclude=None, validate_unique=True):
        super().full_clean(exclude=None, validate_unique=True)  # calling default full_clean
        if self.end_time < self.start_time:
            raise ValidationError("some message")
```

**Reference**
1. [Model.clean() - Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean)
2. [Model.save() - Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save)
3. [Model.full_clean() - Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a "start" and "end" you could have a "start" and "duration" using the [DurationField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#durationfield), then the "end" property is calculated from that.

```
class Period(models.Model):
      number = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
      start_time = models.TimeField()
      duration = models.DurationField()

      @property
      def end_time(self):
          return self.start_time + self.duration
```

You should also be able to use the end time in queries by adding it with the `annotate` method on a queryset, i.e.

```
query = Period.objects.all().annotate(end_time=F('start_time')+F('duration'))
```